# Can I use RelativeDateTimeFormatter (or some other class) to create relative dates with multiple units?

Tags: swift, foundation

Apple's Foundation framework has the `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` class, which lets you describe time intervals relative to the current time. It will generate strings like "Two days ago."

Is it possible to generate strings like "Two days, seven hours and twenty-seven minutes ago" using a `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` or some other Foundation class? (Ideally with control over which units to use?

(The code below generates the string "yesterday".)

```
import Foundation

let formatter = RelativeDateTimeFormatter()
formatter.dateTimeStyle = .named
formatter.unitsStyle = .full

let outputString = formatter.localizedString(fromTimeInterval: -123456.789)

print(outputString)
```

You might think that using the `localizedString(from:)` form would work. (That version takes a `DateComponents` object.) You'd be wrong. It creates a similar, single-unit comparison:

```
let components = DateComponents(day: 2, hour: 3, minute: 7)
let outputString = formatter.localizedString(from: components)
```

That code creates the string "in 2 days."

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` class does not let you control the units it uses.

The older class `DateComponentsFormatter` offers more control, but doesn't add strings like "ago" or "from now" like `RelativeDateTimeFormatter` does.

I just created a simple function that appends those strings to the output of a `DateComponentsFormatter`. See this answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/75565749/205185